# .htaccess redirect to a sub directory not working right

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I am new to htaccess and I have been working on it for whole day. Please help. I just want:

1. www.example.com to be redirected to example.com/hu
2. example.com to be redirected to example.com/hu

Here is the htaccess file that I copied from my typo3 website:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </IfModule>
  FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dnaplus-humangenetikaicentrum\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dnaplus-humangenetikaicentrum.com/hu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It redirects www.example.com to www.example.com/hu. But does not work with example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
# if hostname starts with "www"...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$    #here we get rest of URI as %1

# ...redirect permanently to hostname whitout "www":
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# if client requested root directory:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

# redirect him to start page:
RewriteRule .* hu [R=307,L]
```

I recomend to use exacly temporary redirect (307) to start page. 301 status is hard cached by browsers, so if you will change your start page later, some users still be redirected to old page.

Comment: Solved:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dnaplus-humangenetikaicentrum.com/hu/$1 [L,R=301]